# How do I optimize if else within each of if else block

Tags: javascript

How could I optimize if-else block within each of if-else block...

```
if (condition A)
       if (condition B)
           do action X
       else
           do action Y
else {
       if (condition B)
           do action Y
       else 
           do action X
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could compare the condition results with an exclusive NOR.

```
if (condition A === condition B)
    do action X
else
    do action Y
```

Comment: @NinaScholz how do you know condition A equals condition B? Couldn't they be different?

Comment: @symlink That's a boolean (true\false)

Comment: @NinaScholz oh yeah, of course! I haven't had my coffee yet.

Comment: To handle in case of condition A is 1, condition B is true, we should change the if condition to: condition A == condition B, or Boolean(condition A) == Boolean(condition B).

Comment: @symlink, the original condition is evaluated as a boolean value, if *condition* does not return a boolean, an explicit conversion, like `Boolean(condition A) === Boolean(condtion B)` is required, anyway the code is pseudo code.

Comment: Nina is an expert in this ;) I had to [make my own to double check](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/jn2osexm/)

Comment: @connexo Then you will love the XOR here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61598472/295783

Answer (score 1):

this is an XOR operator

```
if (condition_A ^ condition_B)  action_Y 
else                            action_X
```

proof

```js
const action_X = (r,cA,cB) => console.log( r, cA, cB, 'action X')
const action_Y = (r,cA,cB) => console.log( r, cA, cB, 'action Y')

const test = (ref, condition_A, condition_B ) => {
  if (condition_A ^ condition_B)  action_Y( ref,condition_A,condition_B)
  else                            action_X( ref,condition_A,condition_B)
}

test( 1, true,  true  )
test( 2, false, false )
test( 3, true,  false )
test( 4, false,  true )
```